# addon"simplify curves" don't work

Tags: add-on

[image]Hi, maybe someone had it, please tell me.
Enabled addon, but it is not

Comment: Which curve are you trying to simplify?

Comment: D+left mouse button

Comment: you need to select a curve to make the tool selectable

Answer (score 0):

The addon works only if there are keyframes to work on.

And is meant to work in the Graph editor.